As matrices, what does the regular representation look like?
I've recently been learning representation theory, and so far, I can only really understand it from a 'high-altitude' perspective. That, to understand a group, we want to find appropriate matrices which mimic the behaviour of each group element. In doing so, we can apply concepts of linear algebra. So, $\mathbb{R}S_3$ can be understood as permuting coordinates in $V = \{ (x, y, z) \,|\, x,y,z\in \mathbb{R} \} $. As an example $\pi = (1\, 2)$ permutes the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, and leaves $z$ alone. So, $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y, x, z)$ and hence, $$ (1\, 2)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ And, we can do this for every permutation of $S_3$. I guess, this is one kind of representation of the group $S_3$ in a $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector space, and many other matrices could be called a representation --- so long as the map which associates the permutation to the matrix is a homomorphism.
My question is: what does the regular representation look like as a matrix? For this example, or any other? I understand that the regular representation is meant to multiply with the group elements, but other than that, I don't really get how it 'looks like'. Or what it would mean for any general group. Every single resource I've seen, seems to take the regular representation as very self-evident, but I don't really get it, and unfortunately am desperate for someone to spell it out for me. Thank you for any help.

One way to do it is as follows: For $G$ a finite group, the representation space of the regular representation over $\Bbb{R}$ is the space $W$ of all functions $f:G\to \Bbb{R}$, which is naturally a $\Bbb{R}$-vector space. It should be clear that a basis for this vector space is the set of functions $\lbrace 1_g\mid g\in G\rbrace$, where $1_g(g) = 1$ and $1_g(h) = 0$ for all $h\neq g$. Now, the (right, say) regular representation $\rho:G\to \text{GL}(W)$ is given by
$$(\rho(g) f)(h) = f(hg),$$
i.e. we just multiply on the right by $g$ in the input of $f$. What happens to our basis?
Well, we see that $\rho(g)1_{g'}(h) = 1_{g'}(hg)$, which is $1$ iff $g'=hg$, or equivalently, iff $g'g^{-1} = h$, so it is equal to $1_{g'g^{-1}}(h)$. Since multiplying by $g^{-1}$ just permutes the elements of $G$, we see that $\rho(g)$ just permutes the basis. In particular, if we label $G=\lbrace g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\rbrace$, and identify $1_{g_i}$ with $e_i = (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$, with the $1$ in the $i$'th entry, we see that $\rho(g)$ is the matrix with the i'th column being $e_j^T$, when $g_i g^{-1} = g_j$.
For $G=S_3$, let's take $g=(1 2)$, and let us order its elements as $g_1=(1), g_2=(1 2), g_3=(1 3), g_4=(2 3), g_5=(1 2 3), g_6=(1 3 2)$. Then, as $g^{-1} = g$, we see that $$g_1g^{-1} = g_2,$$ $$g_2g^{-1} = g_1,$$ $$g_3g^{-1} = g_5,$$ $$g_4g^{-1} = g_6,$$ $$g_5g^{-1} = g_3,$$ $$g_6g^{-1} = g_4.$$
Thus, its matrix representation is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.
